# How do I load the proper localized file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, localization

I've got a plist which I localized. How do I load the plist properly?

Right now, I'm using this code:

```
NSArray *numbersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Numbers" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

What do I need to change my code to in order to load the localized plist?

Comment: That should work as-is.  Is it not?

Comment: @DaveDeLong - Yes it, my mistake. I didn't clean my build and delete it from the simulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSArray *numbersArray = [[NSArray alloc]
   initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Numbers" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

This should work provided that you assure that you have the following bundle layout:

```
MyApp.app
 // no Numbers.plist here
.....
en.lproj/
    Numbers.plist // english-version
fr.lproj/
    Numbers.plist // french-version
```

The important thing is that you **do not** have a `Numbers.plist` file at the root level (aka-non-localized level) of the bundle, since if you do, that Numbers.plist will always take precedence over the localized version (for performance reasons).

Comment: Is there a way to load the english-version if the french-version does not exist?

Comment: @yuf: Are you wondering what might happen if you've, for example, localized your Numbers.plist file in `en` & `es` (and not `fr`), and a French user uses your app? I can update the answer to explain, if so...

Comment: yes I am. It is not relevant to this question. I made a separate question and if you can answer it please do!

Comment: @yuf: Actually, it is relevant to this question (since it's all `NSBundle`), but anyway...